# Firefox freezes in foreground

Tags: gnome, firefox, freeze, amd-graphics

While using Firefox actively, it freezes. I can't scroll, nor can I interact in any other way with it. Although it seems like actions are passed through to the program. For example, I am somewhat able to switch tabs, because the view gets updated when the focus of the window is switched to another app.

I am on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and using Firefox (snap) v106.0.5. My extensions are: NoScript, Privacy Badger and uBlock. My hardware is a Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 3 11ADA05 (GPU: Picasso/Raven 2, CPU: AMD 3020e). WM is stock and I'm using Wayland.

For now it seems, that the problem appears to be a lot less often, when Firefox is launched via command line. If it happens, there are no real log entries about it. I've also followed the hints given from [the mozilla troubleshooting page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-extensions-themes-to-fix-problems).

- Disable extensions
- Update extensions
- Use default theme
- Start with safe-mode

Does someone have any clues at hand and is willing to share them?

---

Edit:
I am now testing, if the apt version works better. Steps taken:

```
> cp -R ~/snap/firefox ~/ffback
> sudo snap remove firefox
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
> echo '                                     
Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam
Pin-Priority: 1001
' | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox
> echo 'Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins:: "LP-PPA-mozillateam:${distro_codename}";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/51unattended-upgrades-firefox
> sudo apt install firefox
> cp -R ff_backup/common/.mozilla/firefox ~/.mozilla/
> # start firefox open about:profiles
> # set old restored profile to default
> # restart a few times
```

Comment: same behavior with apt version here, it started like 2-3months ago.
(I am using apt version of forefox only. It is first step I take after install/upgrade)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restoring the apt version of firefox has completely mitigated the issue and even made it a little bit more responsive.

Again, needed steps are below:

```
> cp -R ~/snap/firefox ~/ffback
> sudo snap remove firefox
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
> echo '                                     
Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam
Pin-Priority: 1001
' | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox
> echo 'Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins:: "LP-PPA-mozillateam:${distro_codename}";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/51unattended-upgrades-firefox
> sudo apt install firefox
> cp -R ff_backup/common/.mozilla/firefox ~/.mozilla/
> # start firefox open about:profiles
> # set old restored profile to default
> # restart a few times
```

Comment: apt version has the same problem with freezing in foreground